# How to convert a combination of char, number, symbols to string in Java

Tags: java, string, json

I want to convert the following sequence into a string in an easy way. Is it possible?

The entire part into string.

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "reason": "Records 10 out of 9749.",
    "response": [
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35A",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26076,
                    "Name": " Zaxby's",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-621-0400",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.648151397705078,
                    "longitude": -87.91273498535156,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.7
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.8
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35B",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26076,
                    "Name": " Zaxby's",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-621-0400",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.648151397705078,
                    "longitude": -87.91273498535156,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.7
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.8
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "38",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26100,
                    "Name": " Burger King",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-625-6881",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.65729331970215,
                    "longitude": -87.8520278930664,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "38",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.7
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "38",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "38",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26100,
                    "Name": " Burger King",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-625-6881",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.65729331970215,
                    "longitude": -87.8520278930664,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "38",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.7
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "38",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35A",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26066,
                    "Name": " Hooters",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-625-3910",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.646875381469727,
                    "longitude": -87.91275024414062,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.8
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35B",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26066,
                    "Name": " Hooters",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-625-3910",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.646875381469727,
                    "longitude": -87.91275024414062,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.8
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35A",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26081,
                    "Name": " Hooters",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-625-3910",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.646875381469727,
                    "longitude": -87.91275024414062,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.8
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35B",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26081,
                    "Name": " Hooters",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-625-3910",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.646875381469727,
                    "longitude": -87.91275024414062,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.8
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35A",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26082,
                    "Name": " Ihop",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-621-5630",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.646413803100586,
                    "longitude": -87.91304016113281,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ExitInfo": {
                "exitid": "35B",
                "highwayname": "10",
                "distance": "5943.88684516532",
                "businessCount": "1"
            },
            "listRestaurants": [
                {
                    "ID": 26082,
                    "Name": " Ihop",
                    "Rating": 0,
                    "KidsRating": 0,
                    "RestRoomRating": 0,
                    "City": "Daphne",
                    "State": "AL",
                    "Phone1": "251-621-5630",
                    "Phone2": "",
                    "Phone3": "",
                    "Cuisines": [],
                    "numreviews": 0,
                    "price": "",
                    "isBar": false,
                    "isBarNGrill": false,
                    "isCoffeeShop": false,
                    "isGrill": false,
                    "isHotel": false,
                    "isIceCreamStore": false,
                    "isNightclub": false,
                    "isRestStop": false,
                    "isRestaurant": false,
                    "isIndependent": false,
                    "isChain": true,
                    "latitude": 30.646413803100586,
                    "longitude": -87.91304016113281,
                    "Exits": [
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35A",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 0.9
                        },
                        {
                            "HighWay": 10,
                            "ExitName": "35B",
                            "Direction": "North",
                            "Distance": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "ThumbsUp": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 9749
}
```

Comment: Looks like a pretty nice string to me already. You’re done!

Comment: looks like JSON to me....is it??

Comment: What is the definiton of your "string"? This is already a string, huh.

Comment: Please say what do you want exactly?(because you have a string!)

Comment: i want to covert the entire response into string because i used as hard-coded. that's why i want to convert as string

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var magicTrick = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t')
```

Get it at http://www.json.org/js.html.

Comment: This question is tagged `java` (not `javascript`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a number to a string is to add an empty string to the number. Example:

```
int toString = 3454;

String newString = "" + toString;
```